# how to update CNContact? Get CNErrorDomain Code=2

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

I'm trying to update your contacts in the caste controller, all well preserved up to a point, this is when adding new numbers that have `CNLabeledValue <CNPhoneNumber>` format. I brought in the console result I get this error

```
CNErrorDomain Code = 2 "(null)" UserInfo = {CNKeyPaths = (
     phoneNumbers
)},
```

As I looked at how to create the essence of the hotel and they do not have an example of an indicator

```
<CNLabeledValue: 0x1706755c0: identifier = (null), label = iPhone, value = <CNPhoneNumber: 0x170439100: countryCode = ru, digits = + ***** >>
```

My code

```
  for i in 0..<contactPhoneEditTableViewRowIndex {
        debugPrint("i", i)
        if let editRow = getEditPhoneRow(i) {
            if !editRow.isHidden {
                let phone = editRow.cell.phoneNumberTextField.text ?? ""
                let label = editRow.cell.titlePhoneButton.titleLabel?.text ?? ""
                if phone != "" {
                    let phoneModel = CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>().settingLabel(label, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone))

                    phones.append(phoneModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    debugPrint(phones)

    guard let updatedContactModel = contactModel.contact.mutableCopy() as? CNMutableContact else { return }

    updatedContactModel.givenName = first
    updatedContactModel.familyName = last
    updatedContactModel.organizationName = company
    updatedContactModel.phoneNumbers = phones

    contactManager.updateContact(updatedContactModel) { [weak self] (error) in
        if error == nil {
            self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

This function from ContactManager

```
func updateContact(_ contact: CNMutableContact, completion: ((_ error: Error?) -> Void)?) {
    let req = CNSaveRequest()
    req.update(contact)
    let store = CNContactStore()
    do {
        try store.execute(req)
        debugPrint("updateContact success")
        completion?(nil)
    } catch {
        completion?(error)
        let _error = error as NSError
        debugPrint(_error)
    }
}
```

Tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Hi have you ever got this error while adding / updating the contact `Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=1 "Communication Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Communication Error, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An error occurred while trying to communicate with the Contacts service.}`

Comment: Hi @TheiOSDev I didn't face Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=1

Comment: Thank you @Alexander for your quick reply :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed this code

```
let phoneModel = CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>().settingLabel(label, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone))
```

to                         `let phoneModel = CNLabeledValue(label: phoneLabel, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone))` and it solved my problem